# MySQL deadlock - don't know why

Tags: mysql, sql, deadlock

I have a running system with a MySQL database engine. 
Running the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command shows the:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------

*** (1) TRANSACTION:
UPDATE db.alarm
       LEFT JOIN (db.event, db.alarm1)
         ON db.event.idevent = db.alarm.idevent
           AND db.alarm1.idevent = db.alarm.idevent
       SET
         idalarmseverity =  NAME_CONST('alarmseveritycleared',1),
         lastmodifieddate =  NAME_CONST('moddate',_binary'2015-01-07 09:02:00' COLLATE 'binary')
       WHERE db.event.ideventsource =  NAME_CONST('sourceid',3)
         AND (db.alarm1.idorder =  NAME_CONST('orderid',18894) OR  NAME_CONST('orderid',18894) = 0)
         AND db.alarm.idalarmseverity > 1

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 32942 n bits 440 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `db`.`alarm` trx id 17 2553624600 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
UPDATE db.alarm
       LEFT JOIN (db.event, db.alarm2)
         ON db.event.idevent=db.alarm.idevent
           AND db.alarm2.idevent=db.alarm.idevent
       SET
         idalarmseverity= NAME_CONST('alarmseveritycleared',1),
         lastmodifieddate= NAME_CONST('moddate',_binary'2015-01-07 09:02:00' COLLATE 'binary')
       WHERE db.event.ideventsource= NAME_CONST('sourceid',3)
         AND db.alarm.idalarmseverity > 1

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 32942 n bits 440 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `db`.`alarm` trx id 17 2553624599 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 32941 n bits 440 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `db`.`alarm` trx id 17 2553624599 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
```

At this point I don't know what the 2nd TRANSACTION is waiting for.

The 1st transaction is waiting for a lock (page no 32942) which is hold by the 2nd transaction. That's clear.
But the 2nd transaction is waiting for a lock (page no 32941) which is not hold by anyone.

Or if the 2 locks are the same (or overlaps) than it is the same transaction that currently holds the lock. I don't understand it well enough so it would be great if someone could explain to me how this deadlock could happen and how the UPDATE should be modified to prevent future deadlocks like this.

Thanks